# Can GitSharp return a Leaf (blob) object directly given the leaf's hash?

Tags: c#, git, gitsharp

I noticed that I can get the contents of a particular Leaf (blob)
object from a specific branch by iterating over a Tree's children like
so:

```
      _repository = new Repository(git_url);

      IEnumerable<AbstractObject> currentBranchItems = _repository.CurrentBranch.CurrentCommit.Tree.Children;

               foreach (var currentBranchItem in currentBranchItems)
               {
                   var currentBranchLeaf = currentBranchItem as Leaf;
                   _lastLeafHash = currentBranchLeaf.Hash;
                   Console.WriteLine("Name: " + currentBranchLeaf.Name + " Hash: " + currentBranchLeaf.Hash);
               }
```

However, this seems pretty inefficient if I have the hash of the leaf
that I would like to retrieve. Is there a way that I can access a Leaf
directly from the repository if I have the hash? The following does
not work:

```
 private static void GetLeafByHash(string hash)
       {
               var leafAbs = _repository.Get<AbstractObject>(hash);
               var leaf = leafAbs as Leaf;
               Console.WriteLine("Found Leaf Named: " + leaf.Name);
               Console.WriteLine("The data is this big: " + leaf.RawData.Length);
               Console.Read();        
       }
```

The Get method always returns NULL. So is there a way to accomplish
the direct retrieval of a Leaf by hash? The documentation states the
following about the Get method:

Access a git object by name, id or path. Use the type parameter to
tell what kind of object you like to get. Supported types are
Branches, Commits or Tags may be accessed by name or reference
expression. Currently supported are combinations of these:
Not supported is
Tree or Leaf (Blob) objects can be addressed by long hash or by their
relative repository path

It's not clear.. does this mean that Tree or Leaf objects can or
cannot be accessed via a hash?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get any object in the repo as Blob like this

```
var blob=repo.Get<Blob>(sha_hash);
```

If you know the type of the object (tree, tag or commit) you can also substitute the type parameters Tree, Tag and Commit for T in Get().

Sidenote: In GitSharp a Leaf is a Blob that knows it's path in the tree of the current revision. However since a file can be in many places on different branches and revisions you can not get a Leaf via Repository.Get().